# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting SQL Syntax Error. I don't know why. I have checked everything but couldn't get through this error. I am using Eclipse.
Here is the code for adding user

```
package com.DOA;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import com.User.UserDetails;

public class UserDOA {

    private Connection conn;

    public UserDOA(Connection conn) {
        super();
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public boolean addUser(UserDetails us) {
        boolean f = false;
         
        try {
            String query = "insert into user values (name,email,password) (?,?,?)";
             
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, us.getName());
            ps.setString(2, us.getEmail());
            ps.setString(3, us.getPassword());
            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i==1) {
                f=true;
            }
             
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
        return f;
   }
}
```

Here is the code of Servlet

```
package com.Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;

import com.DOA.UserDOA;
import com.User.UserDetails;
import com.DB.DBConnect;


import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/UserServlet")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet{
           public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String name = request.getParameter("fname");
        String email = request.getParameter("uemail");
        String password = request.getParameter("upassword");
       
        UserDetails us = new UserDetails(); 
        us.setName(name);
        us.setEmail(email);
        us.setPassword(password);
       
        UserDOA dao = new UserDOA(DBConnect.getConn());
        boolean f=dao.addUser(us);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       
        if(f) {
            out.print("User Register Successfully");
        }else {
           out.print("Data not insert");
        }
    }

}
```

I started the Tomcat server, registered an account, but getting data not insert as an output instead of getting the data in the Workbench.

Comment: The only relevant piece of code is your SQL statement. Just check any SQL manual for the syntax for `insert`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i just checked and yeah the values must be after the column names. Simple syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong, it should be:

```
insert into user (name,email,password) values (?,?,?)
```